# PHP echo certain part of url

Tags: php, url, echo

I am not totally sure what I am looking for, but what I basically am trying to do is making a static page more personal by echo the last part of the link I add to the URL.

So if the site link is me.com?=John%20Doe then the page will echo at multiple given places, the name added in the URL by a simple . I have tried a couple of things but none of them worked even slightly.

Could anybody help me with this I would be really grateful, or tell me if it is even possible?

In advance, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about [`GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) parameters.

```
GET me.com?name=John
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
    echo htmlentities($_GET["name"]); //John
?>
```

If you **absolutely** want to not use a `GET` parameter (for any particularly bad coding design reason), you can use `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`:

```
<?php
    echo htmlentities(substr(urldecode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]), 1));
?>
```

Comment: This was vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). `htmlentities` will resolve that (but `htmlspecialcharacters` should be sufficient).

Comment: @Quentin Of course you're right - fixed that up right quick. No need to teach insecure coding standards.

Comment: What if I cant/should not have the me.com?**NAME**=john part? Is it still possible? But even tho, Tanks a great deal @h2ooooooo

Comment: @John-EilifEliassen Parse `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or use an htaccess rewrite.

Comment: Ehm, I am thankful for your help but that sounded complicated with htaccess involved. Been around that once before and completely messed it up. Could i <?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?> then? And will the me.com?= also be included then? I need only the part after the question mark but rather without any suffix before it.

Comment: @John-EilifEliassen I've added an example. You need to actually use `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`, but it'll start with an equal sign (hence why we use `substr`).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `GET` parameter.

Let `particularPage.php`be the page you want to view.

In the address bar of your browser, you'd have something like: `http://url.com/particularPage.php?name=James`

Then on `particularPage.php` you can do:

```
<?php

$variableName = $_GET['name'];

echo $variableName;

?>
```

Everywhere you need to print the name, if your page is mostly HTML, just do:

```
<?php echo $variableName; ?>
```

For example in an input field, you may have:

```
<input name="firstname" type="text" value="<?php echo $variableName; ?>" />
```